# Post response with render partial that has events is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In ruby on rails, I am trying to update 2 partials.

**show.html.erb:**

```
<div id="filters"><%= render :partial => "pricelistfilters" %></div>
```

**pricelistfilters.html.erb:**

```
<% @properties.each do |prop| %>
  #Render the page on properties (and the newproperties)
  #<select ...><option>...</option><option>...</option>
  #</select>
<% end %>
```

**products.js** --> events for the rendered partial

```
$(window).ready(function(){
  selectionchanges();
});
function selectionchanges(){
  $('#filters select').change(function(){
    //Doing stuff to send with ajax

    //Ajax:
    $.ajax({
      url: document.URL,
      type: 'POST',
      data: params
    });
  });
}
```

**products_controller.rb** --> code to process changes made

```
def show
  #Changing the properties (and the pricelist properties)
  @properties #is filled
  @newproperties #is filled
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end 
end
```

**show.js.erb**

```
$('#filters').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "pricelistfilters") %>');
selectionChanges();
```

My rendered item is perfectly good. However, when I've got the proper response with the rendered item, It just doesn't send the ajax anymore. So the event on my select items is gone, whilst I am certain that I've reset them with the "selectionchanges();" on the end of my show.js.erb file?

Can anyone see a solution to this?

Greetings and thanks in advance

Comment: Code blocks were behaving strange: thanks @jdl for helping me out!

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you find a good answer for your problem.

Comment: you have 'selectionchanges' AND 'selectionChanges',  is that a typo?

Comment: is there an error being thrown in your javscript console?

Comment: Yes, it's a typo (sorry) and unfortunately there is no error, should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using jquery's live function on **product.js**, as bellow:

```
$(window).ready(function(){
  selectionchanges();
});
function selectionchanges(){
  $('#filters select').live('change', function(){
    //Doing stuff to send with ajax

    //Ajax:
    $.ajax({
      url: document.URL,
      type: 'POST',
      data: params
    });
  });
}
```

Basically, you're replacing the HTML Dom's element that you first bound the event 'change' to. With live, even by replacing the element, jQuery will re-do the binding for you.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Should have look this one up. Working perfectly! Thanks mate.